# npm error Cannot find module './config/core.js'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start, npm-version

I'm facing an npm issue while utilizing the `npm install` and `npm -v` commands.

Below is the error log for the `npm -v` command when run in Windows Command Prompt:

> ```
> C:\Users\Sameer>npm -v internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905   throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './config/core.js' Require stack:
> - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
> - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
>     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
>     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:25:17
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:502:3)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
>     'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\npm.js',
>     'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'   ] } internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './config/core.js' Require stack:
> - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
> - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
>     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
>     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:25:17
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:502:3)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
>     'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\npm.js',
>     'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'   ] }
> ```

- Node.js Version: **v14.17.1**
- OS: Windows **10**

I tried uninstalling node.js, and also tried installing the new node.js setup directly. However, I'm getting the below error on windows system when uninstalling and installing the node.js rollbacks:

[Node.js uninstall/install error in windows system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmLp0.png)

> Node.js
>
> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2330.

Any workarounds or suggestion to solve this type of issues with npm?
Or any way to uninstall node.js and install a new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall NodeJS, then delete the `C:\Program Files\nodejs` directory, and finally reinstall NodeJS.

Comment: As mentioned above i tried uninstalling node.js but getting error "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package, this may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2330 "  and then uninstalling is also rolled back, same for installing new without uninstalling this one

Comment: I know, but I meant to run the uninstaller even if it gives the error.

Comment: I didn't get you, the uninstall process is automatically terminated because of the error mentioned above

Comment: Then don't uninstall it. Just delete the directory.

Comment: Was not able to un-install but renamed nodejs directory in program files and installed new node.js version, but any suggestion to avoid this type of issue in future Or what causes this type of issue

Comment: It's probably some invalid files or a corrupted installation.